# Laravel mix Не обновляется версия сss файла или version() все портит

Tags: laravel

Использую http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/mix 
Не могу понять как заставить браузер обновлять версии сss файла

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .styles([
        'public/css/app.css'
    ], 'public/css/all.css')
    .browserSync('http://links');
```

Код выше работает прекрасно, но стоит добавить version() для отслеживания версии файлв - перестает работать browserSync, styles.

Задача в том чтобы all.css был с версией + в браузере обновлялась эта версия

Нужно чтобы при сохранении отслеживемых файлов тоько all.css сохранялся с версией + browserSyns понимал это  и обновлял на странице эту версию

Comment: Да ребята поднимали такой [вопрос](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/211) , но как я понял там не webpack методы это фича не работает, зато говорят что после combine можно, попробуй

Comment: Печально обстоят дела